PulseAudio-Jack-Sink shows wrong audio channel names
I use Ubuntu Studio 22.04.4 LTS.
I installed and activated PipeWire (because the 22.04 system version doesn't have a full installation).
Believe it or not, it works... almost fine (not error messages, at least).
But, I found some audio issues about a weird upmixing I didn't have.
Whatever, I discovered a "mistake" inside the PULSEAUDIO-JACK-SINK box (in the audio connections scheme).

As you can see, I expected to get the exactly same audio channel names I have inside the JACK-MIXER box (from top: FRONT CENTER, FRONT LEFT, FRONT RIGHT, REAR CENTER, REAR LEFT, REAR RIGHT, SIDE LEFT and SIDE RIGHT).
How can I fix this?
Also, From where are the "AUX0" and AUX1" connections?
